# Android, NullPointerException in an Adapter's getView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter

I'm currently learning about Android and this is one of my first practice apps.

The app is a 'Daily Selfie' app. It should display a list of items on the screen. Each item should have a thumbnail of an image, and the filename. Clicking on an item should open the image in full screen. There is a camera icon in the action bar. Clicking this should open an existing camera activity on the device. When a picture is taken, that picture should be saved, and then displayed in the list in my app.

I have all the above working. But I have a problem with this scenario: I open the camera activity through my app, then rotate the device sideways, then take a picture, then accept the picture. As it tries to load up my app again, with the list of items, I get a NullPointerException.

I have breakpointed the adapter and figured this out: The list of items in the adapter is there and lets say, of size 10. The first 9 elements are populated and normal, but the last element is null. I dont have this problem if I dont rotate the device when the camera is open.

Any ideas to fix this please?

Heres the code which I think is relevant to the problem (I've omitted some stuff like setting up an alarm, and context menus, I think they are irrelevant here?).

In MainActivity.java:

```
    private File mCurrentPhoto;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mAdapter = new SelfieListAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        readImages();
        getListView().setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

        setupAlarm();
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
    }


    private void readImages(){
        File dir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        for(File f : dir.listFiles()){
            mAdapter.add(f);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem){
        if(menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.camera_item){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
                getOutputMediaFile(); //Sets mCurrentPhoto to a new file with a unique name
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(mCurrentPhoto));
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            mAdapter.add(mCurrentPhoto);
        }
    }


    private void getOutputMediaFile(){
        if(!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
            return;
        }

        File mediaStorageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("DailySelfie", "Failed to create directory");
                return;
            }
        }

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        mCurrentPhoto = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    }
```

And this is the relevant code in the adapter:

```
private static final int THUMBNAIL_WIDTH = 160;
    private static final int THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT = 120;
    List<File> mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;

    public SelfieListAdapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void add(File file){
        mItems.add(file);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selfie, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.thumbnail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            viewHolder.filename = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_filename);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        File selfie = mItems.get(pos);

        Bitmap fullImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selfie.getAbsolutePath());
        viewHolder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(
                Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(fullImage, THUMBNAIL_WIDTH, THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT, true));

        viewHolder.filename.setText(selfie.getName().split("\\.")[0]);
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder{
        ImageView thumbnail;
        TextView filename;
    }
```

The NullPointerException I'm getting is on this line, because selfie is null:

```
Bitmap fullImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selfie.getAbsolutePath());
```

But only for the last element in the list.  Thanks... appreciate any help with this.

And on a side note, are there any glaring bad practices I'm doing here?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Okay, think I've figured out why this is happening, but I don't know how to fix it.
When the device is tilted, is my activity being destroyed and then re-created? Even though its not the current activity? And so mCurrentPhoto is null, so I'm adding a null to the adapter in onActivityResult?

I don't know how to fix this. A null intent is still passed into onActivityResult so theres nothing there that I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you rotate the CameraActivity and come back to your MainActivity, the MainActivity now is also in new orientation. Whenever the screen orientation change the activity is destroyed and recreated that is why mCurrentPhoto is null.

solution -

1- Make the property method for your mCurrentPhoto like below

```
private File getCurrentPhotoFile(){
  return mCurrentPhoto == null ? mCurrentPhoto = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg") : mCurrentPhoto;
}
```

And in your onActivityResult() use this

```
mAdapter.add(getCurrentPhotoFile());
```

or 
2 - Make use of onSaveInstanceState() callback method to save the mCurrentPhoto and on onCreate() or onRestoreInstanceState() get the mCurrentPhoto value from the bundle.